# Group & sort List of object by runtime-known number of properties

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

Hi I have a problem how to group (each group can be sorted as well) and sort list of items - I need a result set of source list, grouped and sorted 
Can anybody help?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<SampleClass> source = GetItemsToProceed();
        // now I want to group by GetPropNameToGroup props
        // and sort each subgroup by GetPropNameToSort
        // So I do sorting first
        IList<SampleClass> sortedList = GetPropNamesToSort()
            .Aggregate<Tuple<SortOrder, string>, IEnumerable<SampleClass>>(source, SortList)
            .ToList();
        // now I want to group already sorted list - HOW??
    }



    public IEnumerable<Tuple<SortOrder, string>> GetPropNamesToGroup()
    {
        return new[] { Tuple.Create(SortOrder.Ascending, "Prop1"), Tuple.Create(SortOrder.Descending, "Prop2") };
    }

    public IEnumerable<SampleClass> SortList(IEnumerable<SampleClass> source, Tuple<SortOrder, string> tuple)
    {
        var alreadyOrdered = source as IOrderedEnumerable<SampleClass>;
        if (alreadyOrdered != null)
        {
            switch (tuple.Item1)
            {
                case SortOrder.Ascending:
                    return alreadyOrdered.ThenBy(_ => GetDataByPropName(_, tuple.Item2));
                case SortOrder.Descending:
                    return alreadyOrdered.ThenByDescending(_ => GetDataByPropName(_, tuple.Item2));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (tuple.Item1)
            {
                case SortOrder.Ascending:
                    return source.OrderBy(_ => GetDataByPropName(_, tuple.Item2));
                case SortOrder.Descending:
                    return source.OrderByDescending(_ => GetDataByPropName(_, tuple.Item2));
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<SortOrder, string>> GetPropNamesToSort()
    {
        return new[] { Tuple.Create(SortOrder.Ascending, "Prop3"), };
    }

    public object GetDataByPropName(SampleClass data, string propName)
    {
        switch (propName)
        {
            case "Prop1":
                return data.Prop1;
            case "Prop2":
                return data.Prop2;
            case "Prop3":
                return data.Prop3;
            case "Prop4":
                return data.Prop4;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    public class SampleClass
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        public int Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }
        public string Prop4 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you should use Dynamic LINQ for this case.http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library

Comment: I cannot use 3rd party libs

Comment: @Lonli-Lokli This is not 3rd party, its from microsoft.

Comment: Ok, but as I understand it's used as LINQ with string presentation. My sample is just sample. Maybe there is a algorythmic solution, without any additional libs?